# Delete Spotify App's IndexDB

Tags: spotify

I am playing with the spotify Apps api, and trying to use the IndexedDB apis.  My database is in a bad state, and i'd like to delete it and start over, but i can't figure out any way to delete this.

**The databases section in resources in the inspector is empty**, and i don't see any indexedDB files in the ~/Library/Application Support/Spotify folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the local storage APIs, you should just be able to use the local storage APIs to remove the file. If that doesn't work, quit Spotify and remove the following folders:

- ~/Library/Application Support/Spotify
- ~/Library/Caches/com.spotify.client

Spotify will then be in a clean state on next launch.

Comment: You can also do this from the inspector.

Show Inspector -> Resources -> Local Storage and remove the entries.